# How can I edit a mutable property in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsmutablearray, uitableview

I am trying to edit a mutable array from a property and can't seem to directly make it work.  Consider the following code that seems to work, but seems also very inefficient;  I have to copy the whole property array just to make a change in one object.  Why can I change the whole "carNames" array, but can't make a change to one of it's objects?

Thank you for any light you might be able to provide...

```
// CarTableViewController.h


// ...


@interface CarTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *carNames;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *carNames;

-(IBAction)addCarButton:(id)sender;
// ...
// --------------------------------------

// -------CarTableViewController.m-------

// ...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Could I somehow run the removeOjectAtIndex: 
        // directly on the carNames Property?  - this code works...

        NSMutableArray *mutablecarNames = [carNames mutableCopy];
        [mutablecarNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        carNames = [mutablecarNames copy];
        [mutablecarNames release];

            // This code doesn't work... Why?
            // [carNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not just calling `[carNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`?

That should work just fine, since it is a mutable array.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it doesn't.  It crashes and complains that I tried to send a mutating method to an immutable object...

-Michael

Comment: Aha, then you must have created the carNames array using a non-mutable construction method - can we see that code?

Or, perhaps you are changing the array somewhere else via copy...

Comment: The carNames array is a property.  The .h file is as follows (there's not much to it).
---------------------------------------------------------
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CarTableViewController : UITableViewController {
 NSMutableArray *carNames;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *carNames;
-(IBAction)addCarButton:(id)sender;

@end
-----------------------------------------------------------------

I initialize the carNames property array by using the following code..
 tableviewcontroller.carNames = sortedCarNameList;

where sortedCarNameList is a mutablearray.

Comment: Your "somewhere else" comment got me thinking... is the setter method using a copy statement?  could I somehow create a custom setter method using mutable copy instead?  If so, do you know what that code would look like?

Comment: Are you really, really sure sortedCarNameList is mutable?  Because the fact is something is setting that array to a non-mutable value. There's no other explanation because mutable arrays do work.  I would suggest setting a watch on the class variable to break whenever the value is changed (right click on class variable in Debugger window and select "watch variable")

Comment: That helped track it down!  I was initializing the sortedCarNameList with the flowing code....

NSMutableArray *carNameList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPathFilename];

NSMutableArray *sortedCarNameList = [carNameList sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];


Apparently the sortedArrayUsingSelector was returning an immutable array which I was then setting to the carNames property. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you got it solved, I thought the fact you were saying it was sorted was a little suspicious... I should have stated that explicitly since in other things I've done I sort first and then make a mutable copy.

Answer (score 7):

You're setting `carNames` to be the result of `[mutableCarNames copy]`, which is an immutable NSArray. You want `mutableCopy` instead.

Comment: Thanks Chuck.  I don't think I made myself clear.  I would like to replace the four lines of code starting with "NSMutableArray ..." with a single line that edits the property directly.  When I try to directly call [carNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row] the program crashes and says "...mutating method sent to immutable object."  I don't understand why the carNames property is immutable when I declared it as mutable.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that my ID is showing as "unknown"... my name is Michael....

Comment: Yes, as I said, you need to make the object a mutable array.